# How can I reach the 'Retry-After' response header using axios?

Tags: rest, axios, header

I'm building a simple Vue2 app with Auth section, which makes requests to REST API service.

So, I have my axios instance:

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  timeout: DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json',
  },
});
```

To make authorization requests I use a separate module:

```
const auth = (api) => ({
  submitPhoneNumber({ userPhone }) {
    return api.get(`auth/${userPhone}`);
  },
});
```

And set it all up together like this:

```
export default {
  auth: auth(instance),
};
```

Then I add my api to Vue as a plugin:

```
export default {
  install(Vue) {
    const vueInstance = Vue;
    vueInstance.prototype.$api = api;
  },
};
```

In the component I access my api-plugin and make a request, extracting status and headers from it:

```
const { status, headers } = await this.$api.auth.submitPhoneNumber({
  userPhone: this.userPhone,
});
```

When I look through the response in chrome devtools, I clearly see a "retry-after" header with number of seconds, after which I can make another request.
Upon receiving the response, I would like to save this number of seconds to some variable and then render a warning message like "Please wait { seconds } to make another submit".

The problem is that in my code I have no such header in the response (while I can see it in devtools, a I said):
[see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksxuf.png)

So, when logging the headers from my response, there are just these:

```
{content-length: '19', content-type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
```

What is the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try `var retrysec = error.response.data.retry_after` that worked for me

Comment: Nope, getting undefined..